# Many to Many in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I can't quite wrap my head around this.

I have a product, that a user can make an offer on.

A user can make an offer on many products, and a product can have many offers at any given moment(think eBay but multiple people sending separate offers)

Do I need a many to many relationship for an offers migration for example, that references both the product and the user with associated fields in the database?

To me it should be

```
User->hasMany('App\Offers')
Product->hasMany('App\Offers')
```

On offers

```
Offer->belongsTo('App\Users')
Offer->belongsTo('App\Product')
```

Obviously this doesn't use many to many but because I have three models im interacting with, how is it best to model this?

Comment: like this:A user has many offers then offers has many products

Answer (score 0):

you should create product_offers pivot table .

Offer model :

```
class Offer extends Model
{

    public function products(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', product_offers);
    }


    public function users(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Product Model:

```
class Product extends Model
{


    public function offers(){
        $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer', product_offers);
    }

}
```

User Model:

```
class User extends Model
{


    public function offers(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
    }

}
```